# How can I check in R if a function is in a list of functions?

Tags: r

```
algos <- c(bnlearn::hc, bnlearn::tabu)
bnlearn::hc %in% algos
```

> Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) :
> 'match' requires vector arguments

I've tried the above with the following error. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can check whether functions are equal by using the `identical` function.

To check for list membership, you will manually need to apply it to the list:

```
any(vapply(algos, identical, logical(1L), bnlearn::hc))
```

And you can of course wrap that into a function/operator:

```
`%fin%` = function (fun, funs) {
    any(vapply(funs, identical, logical(1L), match.fun(fun)))
}
```

```
bnlearn::hc %fin% algos
```

Answer (score 1):

If you build your list as a named list in the first place:

```r
algos <- c("bnlearn::hc" = bnlearn::hc, "bnlearn::tabu" = bnlearn::tabu)
```

You could simply do:

```r
"bnlearn::hc" %in% names(algos)
```

> `TRUE`